# How does one go from unrealised paramatma or Brahman to atma and body?

Tags: vedanta, advaita

This might be a classical question and it might be interpreted as an argument against vedanta but I'll put my thoughts here and invite you to discuss:

My awareness is limited to my personal body. I sleep and I wake up and I find a permanence of experience. However if I am really consciousness, why am I not experiencing consciousness of everything in the universe simultaneously? Why is this consciousness locked on to my body? Logically it makes sense for my consciousness to permeate the entire universe much akin to that of Brahman.

Vedanta says that the knower and the known are different. This is how we arrive at the conclusion that 'sakshi' or the witness consciousness is a different entity from that what is observed implying that this mind and its witness are different but is this claim backed by any logic? Why is it impossible for the mind which forms all kinds of sensations to not have a sensation of 'itself'. The way I see it, the mind has all power to conjure up an image of itself. And that is where the matter would end. When one is under a deep meditation or anesthesia, one can forgo this sense of self and see experience for what it is, detached from his own body. Then if you up the dose or the depth of meditation, even those experiences vanish. Thus ultimately, I arrive at the conclusion that the consciousness we associate with ourselves is vastly different from the universal consciousness.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the question.  Right now your question is **How does one go from unrealised paramatma or Brahman to atma and body?**.  Do you want to say **How does one go from unrealised paramatma or body to Brahman or atma ?**, because the stage of ** unrealised paramatma** is called **body consciousness**. Please check

Comment: My assumption is that brahman as defined as universal consciousness should be a consciousness of everything. That is information beyond the perception of human beings. What I'm interested in is the transition from this universal consciousness to a personal consciousness which is attached to my body.

Comment: Then you may delete the word "unrealised" before paramatma,  because paramatma indicates universal consciousness

Comment: quite the contrary. brahman or the substratum of reality realises into me. just like I can realise a pot out of clay.

Comment: In your question you had stated  **why am I not experiencing consciousness of everything in the universe simultaneously?**.  Now in the comment section, you are saying  **brahman or the substratum of reality realises into me**.  Please check.  Something is wrong at some place

Comment: Brahman is defined to be universal consciousness isn't it?

Comment: Brahman doesn't or isn't entangled in samsara 1st point.  Its Brahman's svabhava adhyatma, the self , feels itself as separate from Brahman due to reflection of brahman's maya shakti. Thus the self gets embodied in brahman's reflection of maya of mind and buddhi. Thus when sukshma the jeeva gets embodied in sthula, the life on earth begins.

Comment: The consciousness isn't locked in body. Just deeply see rather this body appears in the Chit. Not other way. Right now the jeeva is entangled in manas and buddhi. That's why lot of confusions.  Sadhana alone ll clear ur doubts

Comment: When jeeva frees itself from modifications of prakriti it realises it's none other than Brahman. Thus it the induviduality dies out and it becomes one with Parabrahman.